# Spark:Error writing stream to file /XXX/stderr java.io.IOException: Stream closed

Tags: apache-spark, ioexception

My codes are as below:

```
object WordCount extends App{
  val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("WordCount").setMaster("spark://sparkmaster:7077")
  val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
  sc.addJar("/home/found/FromWindows/testsSpark/out/artifacts/untitled_jar/untitled.jar")
  val file = sc.textFile("hdfs://192.168.1.101:9000/Texts.txt")
  val count = file.flatMap(line => line.split(" ")).map(word => (word,1)).reduceByKey(_+_)
  val res = count.collect()
  res.foreach(println(_))
}
```

When I  run it as local mode,everything is OK.However,when running it on cluster,it would crash.I have got the following error messages:

1.error message from intellij console

```
16/04/24 19:17:34 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 1.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 1, 192.168.1.101): java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.klordy.test.WordCount$$anonfun$2
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
...
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
16/04/24 19:17:34 INFO TaskSetManager: Lost task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0) on executor 192.168.1.101: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException (org.klordy.test.WordCount$$anonfun$2) [duplicate 1]
16/04/24 19:17:34 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 0.1 in stage 0.0 (TID 2, 192.168.1.101, ANY, 2133 bytes)
16/04/24 19:17:34 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 1.1 in stage 0.0 (TID 3, 192.168.1.101, ANY, 2133 bytes)
16/04/24 19:17:34 INFO TaskSetManager: Lost task 1.1 in stage 0.0 (TID 3) on executor 192.168.1.101: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException (org.klordy.test.WordCount$$anonfun$2) [duplicate 2]
16/04/24 19:17:34 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 1.2 in stage 0.0 (TID 4, 192.168.1.101, ANY, 2133 bytes)
16/04/24 19:17:34 ERROR TaskSetManager: Task 1 in stage 0.0 failed 4 times; aborting job
16/04/24 19:17:34 INFO TaskSchedulerImpl: Cancelling stage 0
16/04/24 19:17:34 INFO TaskSchedulerImpl: Stage 0 was cancelled
16/04/24 19:17:34 INFO DAGScheduler: ShuffleMapStage 0 (map at WordCount.scala:17) failed in 2.904 s
16/04/24 19:17:34 INFO DAGScheduler: Job 0 failed: collect at WordCount.scala:18, took 3.103414 s
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 1 in stage 0.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 1.3 in stage 0.0 (TID 6, 192.168.1.101): java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.klordy.test.WordCount$$anonfun$2
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
...
at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:214)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:140)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.klordy.test.WordCount$$anonfun$2
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
...
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
16/04/24 19:17:34 INFO SparkContext: Invoking stop() from shutdown hook
16/04/24 19:17:34 INFO TaskSetManager: Lost task 0.3 in stage 0.0 (TID 7) on executor 192.168.1.101: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException (org.klordy.test.WordCount$$anonfun$2) [duplicate 7]
16/04/24 19:17:34 INFO TaskSchedulerImpl: Removed TaskSet 0.0, whose tasks have all completed, from pool 
16/04/24 19:17:34 INFO SparkDeploySchedulerBackend: Registered executor: AkkaRpcEndpointRef(Actor[akka.tcp://sparkExecutor@192.168.1.117:45350/user/Executor#2034500302]) with ID 0
16/04/24 19:17:34 INFO SparkUI: Stopped Spark web UI at http://192.168.1.101:4040
16/04/24 19:17:34 INFO DAGScheduler: Stopping DAGScheduler
16/04/24 19:17:34 INFO SparkDeploySchedulerBackend: Shutting down all executors
16/04/24 19:17:34 INFO SparkDeploySchedulerBackend: Asking each executor to shut down
16/04/24 19:17:34 INFO MapOutputTrackerMasterEndpoint: MapOutputTrackerMasterEndpoint stopped!
```

2.message from spark logs:

```
    16/04/24 19:17:27 INFO Worker: Asked to launch executor app-20160424191727-0005/1 for WordCount
16/04/24 19:17:27 DEBUG AkkaRpcEnv$$anonfun$actorRef$lzycompute$1$1$$anon$1: [actor] handled message (1.327376 ms) AkkaMessage(LaunchExecutor(spark://sparkworker:7077,app-20160424191727-0005,1,ApplicationDescription(WordCount),2,1024),false) from Actor[akka://sparkWorker/deadLetters]
16/04/24 19:17:27 INFO SecurityManager: Changing view acls to: root
16/04/24 19:17:27 INFO SecurityManager: Changing modify acls to: root
16/04/24 19:17:27 INFO SecurityManager: SecurityManager: authentication disabled; ui acls disabled; users with view permissions: Set(root); users with modify permissions: Set(root)
16/04/24 19:17:27 DEBUG SSLOptions: No SSL protocol specified
16/04/24 19:17:27 DEBUG SSLOptions: No SSL protocol specified
16/04/24 19:17:27 DEBUG SSLOptions: No SSL protocol specified
16/04/24 19:17:27 DEBUG SecurityManager: SSLConfiguration for file server: SSLOptions{enabled=false, keyStore=None, keyStorePassword=None, trustStore=None, trustStorePassword=None, protocol=None, enabledAlgorithms=Set()}
16/04/24 19:17:27 DEBUG SecurityManager: SSLConfiguration for Akka: SSLOptions{enabled=false, keyStore=None, keyStorePassword=None, trustStore=None, trustStorePassword=None, protocol=None, enabledAlgorithms=Set()}
16/04/24 19:17:27 INFO ExecutorRunner: Launch command: "/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_51/bin/java" "-cp" "/usr/local/Spark/spark-1.5.1-bin-hadoop2.4/sbin/../conf/:/usr/local/Spark/spark-1.5.1-bin-hadoop2.4/lib/spark-assembly-1.5.1-hadoop2.4.0.jar:/usr/local/Spark/spark-1.5.1-bin-hadoop2.4/lib/datanucleus-api-jdo-3.2.6.jar:/usr/local/Spark/spark-1.5.1-bin-hadoop2.4/lib/datanucleus-core-3.2.10.jar:/usr/local/Spark/spark-1.5.1-bin-hadoop2.4/lib/datanucleus-rdbms-3.2.9.jar:/usr/local/Spark/hadoop-2.5.2/etc/hadoop/" "-Xms1024M" "-Xmx1024M" "-Dspark.driver.port=49473" "-XX:MaxPermSize=256m" "org.apache.spark.executor.CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend" "--driver-url" "akka.tcp://sparkDriver@192.168.1.101:49473/user/CoarseGrainedScheduler" "--executor-id" "1" "--hostname" "192.168.1.101" "--cores" "2" "--app-id" "app-20160424191727-0005" "--worker-url" "akka.tcp://sparkWorker@192.168.1.101:49838/user/Worker"
16/04/24 19:17:28 DEBUG FileAppender: Started appending thread
16/04/24 19:17:28 DEBUG FileAppender: Opened file /usr/local/Spark/spark-1.5.1-bin-hadoop2.4/work/app-20160424191727-0005/1/stdout
16/04/24 19:17:28 DEBUG FileAppender: Started appending thread
16/04/24 19:17:28 DEBUG FileAppender: Opened file /usr/local/Spark/spark-1.5.1-bin-hadoop2.4/work/app-20160424191727-0005/1/stderr
16/04/24 19:17:34 DEBUG AkkaRpcEnv$$anonfun$actorRef$lzycompute$1$1$$anon$1: Received RPC message: AkkaMessage(KillExecutor(spark://sparkworker:7077,app-20160424191727-0005,1),false)
16/04/24 19:17:34 INFO Worker: Asked to kill executor app-20160424191727-0005/1
16/04/24 19:17:34 DEBUG AkkaRpcEnv$$anonfun$actorRef$lzycompute$1$1$$anon$1: [actor] handled message (0.172782 ms) AkkaMessage(KillExecutor(spark://sparkworker:7077,app-20160424191727-0005,1),false) from Actor[akka://sparkWorker/deadLetters]
16/04/24 19:17:34 INFO ExecutorRunner: Runner thread for executor app-20160424191727-0005/1 interrupted
16/04/24 19:17:34 INFO ExecutorRunner: Killing process!
16/04/24 19:17:34 ERROR FileAppender: Error writing stream to file /usr/local/Spark/spark-1.5.1-bin-hadoop2.4/work/app-20160424191727-0005/1/stderr
java.io.IOException: Stream closed
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.getBufIfOpen(BufferedInputStream.java:162)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:272)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:334)
    at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:107)
    at org.apache.spark.util.logging.FileAppender.appendStreamToFile(FileAppender.scala:70)
    at org.apache.spark.util.logging.FileAppender$$anon$1$$anonfun$run$1.apply$mcV$sp(FileAppender.scala:39)
    at org.apache.spark.util.logging.FileAppender$$anon$1$$anonfun$run$1.apply(FileAppender.scala:39)
    at org.apache.spark.util.logging.FileAppender$$anon$1$$anonfun$run$1.apply(FileAppender.scala:39)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.logUncaughtExceptions(Utils.scala:1699)
    at org.apache.spark.util.logging.FileAppender$$anon$1.run(FileAppender.scala:38)
16/04/24 19:17:34 DEBUG FileAppender: Closed file /usr/local/Spark/spark-1.5.1-bin-hadoop2.4/work/app-20160424191727-0005/1/stderr
16/04/24 19:17:34 DEBUG AkkaRpcEnv$$anonfun$actorRef$lzycompute$1$1$$anon$1: [actor] received message AkkaMessage(ApplicationFinished(app-20160424191727-0005),false) from Actor[akka://sparkWorker/deadLetters]
16/04/24 19:17:34 DEBUG AkkaRpcEnv$$anonfun$actorRef$lzycompute$1$1$$anon$1: Received RPC message: AkkaMessage(ApplicationFinished(app-20160424191727-0005),false)
16/04/24 19:17:34 DEBUG AkkaRpcEnv$$anonfun$actorRef$lzycompute$1$1$$anon$1: [actor] handled message (0.186628 ms) AkkaMessage(ApplicationFinished(app-20160424191727-0005),false) from Actor[akka://sparkWorker/deadLetters]
16/04/24 19:17:35 DEBUG FileAppender: Closed file /usr/local/Spark/spark-1.5.1-bin-hadoop2.4/work/app-20160424191727-0005/1/stdout
16/04/24 19:17:35 DEBUG AkkaRpcEnv$$anonfun$actorRef$lzycompute$1$1$$anon$1: [actor] received message AkkaMessage(ExecutorStateChanged(app-20160424191727-0005,1,KILLED,None,Some(143)),false) from Actor[akka://sparkWorker/deadLetters]
16/04/24 19:17:35 DEBUG AkkaRpcEnv$$anonfun$actorRef$lzycompute$1$1$$anon$1: Received RPC message: AkkaMessage(ExecutorStateChanged(app-20160424191727-0005,1,KILLED,None,Some(143)),false)
16/04/24 19:17:35 INFO Worker: Executor app-20160424191727-0005/1 finished with state KILLED exitStatus 143
16/04/24 19:17:35 INFO Worker: Cleaning up local directories for application app-20160424191727-0005
```

Really puzzled about this, any good idea solving this?
   My cluster environment is:Spark 1.5.1/hadoop 2.5.2/scala 2.10.4/jdk1.7.0_51.

Comment: Are you sure `sc.addJar("/home/found/FromWindows/testsSpark/out/artifacts/untitled_jar/untitled.jar")` is the correct location of the file? You can see in the Spark logs if it is able to pick up the driver and send it over to the workers.

Comment: I am sure the location is right.The codes crashed when call RDD's collect() at `val res = count.collect()`.

Comment: That's because that's when the RDD is being materialized.

Comment: T.T yeah,so what is the reason?I am pretty sure the path to jar file is right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem has been solved.The main reason is that my project have imported two versions of scala(one extra version from sbt downloading).Thanks for guys who helped me solving this problem.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that `sc.addJar("/home/found/FromWindows/testsSpark/out/artifacts/untitled_jar/untitled.jar")` fails on your executor, because that path / jar does not exist on the executor node. Try putting the `jar` into HDFS and using an HDFS path to specify it, so that your executors have access to it.

Or even better, use the `--jars` comand line option to `spark-submit` and specify your `jar` there, and then you don't have to change your code and recomple when you change your `jar`.

Comment: What do you mean Hadoop path?I just tried to move my whole project to `/usr/local/Spark/untitled`.And this still not work.

Comment: Sorry, I should have said HDFS not Hadoop to be more clear -- edited my answer. If you don't have HDFS, then you have to put the jar file in the exact same location on every single executor node, or like I said -- just use `--jars` with `spark-submit`

Comment: I have just tried this way,and it seems not work.T.T